# Sent back to the login page all the time even though I'm logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, session-cookies

I've designed the following login code.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult LogIn(string token)
{
  using (Model model = new Model())
    if (model.Users.Any(_ => _.Token == token))
    {
      FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(token, false);
      return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
  return View();
}
```

When I access the page, I get into the login action and enter the credentials. Then, the redirection occurs. When I again want to click on the site I've tried to access in the first place, I get sent back to the login page. Like if the last login isn't remembered or as if the cookie hasn't been set or simply expired.

The other paqe that I'm trying to access looks like this.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "User,Admin")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
  using (Model model = new Model())
    return View(model.Groups.ToList());
}
```

What can I be missing? How to resolve it?

Comment: Did you create a custom RoleProvider ? If not, the user logged in will not have any role.

Comment: Info for using [forms authentication with MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398049(v=vs.100).aspx). However, if you are making a new application, you should use [`ASP.NET Identity`](http://www.asp.net/identity) instead. The default MVC 5 template sets up the basics for you.

Comment: Have you tried removing the roles and check the redirection? May be some problem with roles?

Comment: @Kalten I haven't. Based on your comment, I remembered that I forgot to add claims, though, to the *HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication* and also to invoke *SingIn* method. Now, that I've done that, it works. However, I feel that your comment suggested a different approach. Would you care to elaborate? Is the role provider of yours something that was used before ASP.NET Identity (I'm using OWIN, as NightOwl888 suggested).

Comment: @NightOwl888 I forgot to invoke *SignIn* with correct set of claims (I know, I know - kick me hard). Now it works. However, I wonder if I still do it correctly because another user suggested using a custom role provider. Should I use it even with OWIN and ASP.NET Identity or is it a thing from the time of forms authentication?

Comment: RoleProvider is the old way to handle roles. This is different from owin/Aspnet identity but not so far.

Comment: @Kalten So.Much. Clearer.